# Rails - cannot run app on Heroku because of uncompiled assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets

When I run the app I deployed to Heroku, I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ('fontawesome.less' wasn't found
```

I've tried precompile the assets locally - this way:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The result:

```
...
FATAL:  database "myapp_production" does not exist
...
```

When I run - `heroku run rake assets:precompile`, the result is:

```
...
'fontawesome.less' wasn't found
...
```

The setup in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  config.assets.compile = true
```

What causes this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve the database config issue to be able to compile assets locally.

The assets compiled will all be `.css`, not `less`.

Check `config/application.rb`, I for example have these lines there:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "flash")
config.assets.precompile += [ 'print.css', 'resume.css', 'application.css', 'reset-min.css', 'lightbox.css', 'bootstrap.css', 'grid.css' ]
config.assets.precompile += [ 'rails.js', 'application.js', 'bootstrap.js' ]
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have less-rails gem and the sufix of the file is .css.less

> gem 'less-rails'

If you require the file separately of the application.js, you need to add the precompile array in environments/production.rb, and the extension of the file should be ".css.less"

> config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome.css )

And be sure of you have enable the static_assets option in environments/production.rb

> config.serve_static_assets = true